# On acquire/release semantics not being commutative to other threads

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

The gcc wiki [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) provides an example on memory ordering constraints.

In the below example, the wiki asserts that, if the memory ordering in use is an acquire/release, then `thead-2`'s assert is guaranteed to succeed while `thread-3`'s assert can fail.

```
 -Thread 1-       -Thread 2-                   -Thread 3-
 y.store (20);    if (x.load() == 10) {        if (y.load() == 10)
 x.store (10);      assert (y.load() == 20)      assert (x.load() == 10)
                    y.store (10)
                  }
```

I don't see how that is possible. My understanding is that since `Thread-2`'s `y.store(10)` synchronizes with `Thread-3`'s `y.load()` and since `y` can be `10` if and only if `x` is `10`, I say the `assert` in `Thread-3` should succeed. The wiki disagrees. Can someone explain why?

Comment: if Thread 2 view 10 in x - not mean that Thread 3 will view 10 in x too

Comment: @NicolBolas Seems OP posted the wrong link accidentally. Probably meant https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync.

Comment: @user17732522: But that page says, "Neither assert in this example can fail". So what is the OP asking about?

Comment: @NicolBolas - this is for  sequentially consistent mode. but for Release/acquire mode - "thread 3's assert can fail."

Comment: @NicolBolas The example is mentioned twice in the wiki. The first time it assumes sequential consistency. In the second one it assumes only acquire/release. The claim that the thread 3 assert may fail comes from there.

Comment: @user17732522 - but here exist explain why -  "There has been no synchronization between threads 1 and 3, so no value can be assumed for 'x' there." - but you assume exactly sequentially consistent mode in self logic

Comment: @RbMm I am not the OP. Why OP isn't happy with that explanation, I don't know.

Comment: @user17732522 yes, sorry, i confused you with OP

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I accidentally posted the wrong URL.

Comment: @NicolBolas It comes from gcc wiki, I accidentally posted the wrong URL. Why did I use the relaxed operations tag? Because I had intended to ask about relaxed atomics but forgot to remove the tag when I changed my mind. Why did I forget? Because I'm human.

Comment: [Triggered flashvback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-eZeVwnVOo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and since y can be 10 if and only if x is 10,

And that's the part that is incorrect.

An acquire/release pair works between a releasing store operation and an acquiring load operation which reads the value that was release-stored.

In thread 1, we have a releasing store to `x`. In thread 2, we have an acquiring load from `x`. If thread 2 read the value stored by thread 1, then the two threads have an acquire/release relationship. What that means is that any values written to other objects in thread 1 before the releasing store are visible to thread 2 after its acquiring load.

In thread 2, we have a releasing store to `y`. In thread 3, we have an acquiring load from `y`. If thread 3 read the value stored by thread 2, then the two threads have an acquire/release relationship. What that means is that any values written to other objects in thread 2 before the releasing store are visible to thread 3 after its acquiring load.

But notice what I said: "any values written to other objects ***in thread 2***".

`x` was not written by thread 2; it was written by thread 1. And thread 3 has no relationship to thread 1.

Pure acquire/release is not transitive. If you need transitive access to memory, then you need sequential consistency. Indeed, that's what `seq_cst` is for: ensuring consistently across all acquire/releases which transitively rely on each other.

Note that this is primarily about caches. A pure acquire/release operation may only flush certain caches, particularly if the compiler can  clearly see exactly what memory a thread is making available in a release.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me since the question is lacking explicit memory ordering arguments. If Thread 3 is loading `x` with a `memory_order_acquire`, why would that have anything to do with transitivity? Why doesn't it synchronize with Thread 1 as well? I understand why transitivity would apply if it is a relaxed load.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: The question says that it assumes acquire/release memory orderings are used. The website it copies the example from examines the behavior of this code from the perspective of different memory orderings being used.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: "*I understand why transitivity would apply if it is a relaxed load.*" That is incorrect; relaxed loads would mean absolutely *nothing*, no ordering anywhere.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: "*why would that have anything to do with transitivity?*" Because that's the way acquire/release semantics are defined to work.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question, so to clarify, as long as you combine relaxed ordering with stronger synchronization, you will have well defined ordering.

Comment: "Because that's the way acquire/release semantics are defined to work" can you provide a citation? You have an `acquire` load, why does that not synchronize with the store in thread 1?

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: That depends on how you combine them. It is *in theory* possible, but I don't see how a combination in this particular example would achieve anything.

Comment: Right, so your assertion that "would mean absolutely nothing, no ordering anywhere" is incorrect.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: This is not a language-lawyer question, and sifting through the particulars of the specification to find out exactly where this is specified is not something I'm interested in. The GCC wiki article makes it clear that this is the case, a cursory examination of [the standard behavior for `seq_cst`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/atomics#order-4) tells me it provides a global, transitive guaranteed order of operations. So I see enough evidence to assume the wiki is correct that acquire/release is not transitive without having to do a deep dive.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR: "*Right, so your assertion that "would mean absolutely nothing, no ordering anywhere" is incorrect.*" My assertion was "relaxed loads would mean absolutely nothing, no ordering anywhere". Note that there was no statement about other acquire/release loads or stores that might affect that. You did not state that you were talking about mixing relaxed loads with others, and you're talking in the context of a question which presumes that all load/store operations use the same kind of memory order.